# Merge BootStrap column into another column in Angular HTML

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I am using `Angular`, `Angular Material` and `Bootstrap` in my current project.

I have the below code to divide the 12 columns into 6,1,5 sizes

The sample code is given below..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

The 2nd column is divided into 2 columns.

Now I would like to merge the 2nd column's 2nd column to be merged with the 3rd main column because the gap is more with the current code.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: please provide more details, you can just create a nested column on the third column and cut and paste right? what is the exact issue?

Comment: I got the solution for this. I just used padding to create a gap of 1 column in the middle.

Comment: Great! do give more details next time :)

Comment: Thank you. Will provide more details next time.